# Select Data According to a Partial Match

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data frames and want to merge them.

```
df1 = data.frame(zipcoide=c(90001,90002,90003,66062,90005))
df1

df2 = data.frame(sfc_code=c(900,660,800,400,500,100,300,350,310,450))
df2
```

SCF Codes are apparently zipcode prefixes and I want to match the sfc_code with the zipcode.

Basically, if I'm given a list of scf codes, I want to select all those zipcodes which have that scf code.

So in this example, I want to end up with

```
90001
90002
90003
90005
```

I figure I could use the sqldf package to write a query to select based on " LIKE' %900% " but was looking for something a little more "elegant."

Thanks!

Comment: I just threw in a random number, wasn't meant to be anything special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to return the all the zipcodes whose first 3 digits appear in your `sfc_codes` list:

```
df1[ as.numeric(substr( df1$zipcoide , 1 , 3 ) ) %in% df2$sfc_code , ]
# [1] 90001 90002 90003 66062 90005
```

Probably not the best example because *all* zip codes are in *that* `sfc_code` list!

But if we remove `660` then we get:

```
df2 = data.frame(sfc_code=c(900,800,400,500,100,300,350,310,450))
df1[ as.numeric(substr( df1$zipcoide , 1 , 3 ) ) %in% df2$sfc_code , ]
# [1] 90001 90002 90003 90005
```

Answer (score 1):

When you sfc_code are always the first three digits of your zipcode you could just select the first three digits of your zipcode and match these with the sfc_codes:

```
df1$sfc_code <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(df1$zipcoide), 1, 3))

match(df1$sfc_code, df2$sfc_code)
```

**Update**

If as @joran commented you want to have for each sfc_code in df2 all zipcodes in df1, you could use `merge` (with or without `all=TRUE`):

```
# add id so that we can see which records are matched
df1$id1 <- 1:nrow(df1)
df2$id2 <- 1:nrow(df2)
merge(df2, df1)
```

Comment: Won't that return only the first match, not all matches?

Comment: @joran In the example data set this does not happen, but I have modified the answer to also include this case.

Comment: Actually, no, I think you have it backwards. You're matching _into_ df1, where there are three zip codes that begin with 900. I believe the OP does in fact want to return all of those matches. But `merge` or `%in%` are probably the better way to go here.

Comment: @joran Hmm, I think you're right. It seems he wants for each sfc_code in df2 all zipcodes in df1. I will edit.